# Re-using entry types across multiple sections

Tags: entry-type

Is there way to a create an entry type that you can re-use on different sections?

Essentially what I would like to do is define one entry type, such as a "Product" entry type, and add fields for a product. Then I'd assign this "Product" entry type to each section, as required.

This would prevent me from having to create a "Product" entry type on every section and add the same fields to each one.

Comment: If you're worried about the **creation** of the entryTypes, then you can use [the Architect](http://github.com/Pennebaker/craftcms-thearchitect) to model one, export it, and then re-import it as many times as necessary. It won't help with managing the entryTypes on an ongoing basis, but it'll eliminate the repetition when you configure the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Entry Types are unique to their Sections. You can't have one Entry type shared between multiple Sections. You can however use Field Groups to set your Field Layouts for each Entry Type. This will remove the need to add each and every field individually to each Entry Type.

More info on [Field Layouts](https://craftcms.com/docs/fields#field-layouts) can be found on the docs.